# How to shuffle a list with Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, random, simulator, fault, gaussian

I want to simulate fault on a message (Eg: 1000010011 => 1010000011). Is there a way to implement this in Python? I tried the following, which works:

```
import random
a = "1011101101"
b = [el for el in a] # b = ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1']
random.shuffle(b)
print b # b = ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0']
random.shuffle(b, random.random)
print b # b = ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1']
```

I would like my reordering to be Normally/Gaussian distributed.
Eg:

```
import random
a = "1011101101"
b = [el for el in a] # b = ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1']
random.shuffle(b,random.gauss(0.5,0.1))
print b # b = ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'] <= assume this is Gaussian distributed...
# OR
c = random.gauss(0.5,0.1)
random.shuffle(b,c)
print b # b = ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'] <= assume this is also Gaussian distributed...
```

However, this does not work, and I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 287, in shuffle
    j = int(random() * (i+1))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Any suggestion/comment would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Note: I am only asking for re-ordering error here(Eg: 1000010011 => 1010000011). However, I am also planning on simulating burst-error(Eg: 1000010011 => 1011111011), single events(Eg: 1000010011 => 1000010011), etc.

Other related question: [Python: binary string error simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703464/python-binary-string-error-simulation)

Comment: You could replace your list comprehension for `b` with a simple `b = list(a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of `random.shuffle` should be a callable, not a float. Try:

```
random.shuffle(b, lambda:random.gauss(0.5,0.1))
```

To cap in the interval from 0 to 1, you could use

```
random.shuffle(b, lambda: max(0.0, min(1.0, random.gauss(0.5,0.1))))
```

(Thanks @DSM)

If you're pedantic, the above capping actually includes 1.0, which would lead to an error in `random.shuffle`. You should in fact replace 1.0 by the largest float smaller than 1.0.

Comment: Note that depending on the parameters it might be necessary to cap the random results to make sure they're in `[0.0, 1.0)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
c = lambda: random.gauss(0.5,0.1)
```